# Feature request: Question or answer length indicator in review

Tags: feature-request, review, moderation

I often find very short, or very long answers, in need of the most attention. As of today, the review system does not indicate the post length.

There are, of course, both long and short questions/answers that are perfect the way they are, but when newbies posts questions/answers that are 40 characters in length more often than not the question/answer needs more work.

Comment: I believe these checks already occur and you can see them  under low quality posts in `/review` for >2k users with the edit privilege... I'm quite certain post length is a factor there if only for short posts...

Comment: So why are the length not visible for <2k users? They can still review.

Comment: The use of having answer body length available in other modes than "low quality" is substantial, at least for me.